# My app is white with activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest, splash-screen

Simply because at the time of my splash screen, it does a quick check and have to play for an activity (webview or error activity). But always after the splash screen it is with activity all white.

**My class Splash:**

```
    private static int tempo_splash = 1000;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); // Para o layout preencher toda tela do cel (remover a barra de tit.)

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(Splash.this, MyConnectivityChecker.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();//this should be after starting intent
            }
        }, 2000);

    }
}
```

**Now, my Manifest:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- Activity MainActivity-->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <!-- Activity Splash-->
        <activity android:name=".Splash"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Activity MyConnectivityChecker-->
        <activity android:name=".MyConnectivityChecker"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true">

        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Follow my Check:

```
public class MyConnectivityChecker extends Activity {


    public void verificaInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()!= null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        } else {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, CheckInternet.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }

}
```

**And my Splash xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgrounds">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide your `splash.xml` layout file too.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that your main activity is not starting correctly after the splash screen finishes. Is that correct? Have you tried running the `MyConnectivityChecker` activity directly?

Comment: what is inside MyConnectivityChecker?? I think this activity of yours is empty.

Comment: @Roozbehhz Not empty. Look my code.

Comment: you posted it as an answer??

Comment: Not. incrementing the question...

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyConnectivityChecker` activity never calls `setContentView`; it doesn't even have an `onCreate` method. That's why it's showing up blank after the splash screen exits.

EDIT: Based on the revised description of the problem, I recommend that you get rid of the `MyConnectivityChecker` activity. Instead, check the connectivity inside the splash activity itself. To account for possible changes to the device configuration while the splash screen is sleeping, you should keep a reference to the `Timer` and cancel it if the splash activity is destroyed, something like this (untested):

```
private Timer mTimer;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override public void run() {
                mTimer = null;
                endSplashActivity(isConnected());
            }
        },
        tempo_splash
    );
}

private boolean isConnected() {
    final ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}

private void endSplashActivity(boolean isConnected) {
    Class<?> nextActivity = isConnected ? MainActivity.class : CheckInternet.class;
    startActivity(new Intent(this, nextActivity));
    finish();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: but my class `MyConnectivityChecker` not have layout xml for increment the method onCreate.

Comment: @KevinJhon - Then why are you using `MyConnectivityChecker` as an activity? It is showing up as a blank screen because you have not designed a user interface for it. Perhaps you need to explain what goal you have for the user experience.

Comment: because it will serve only to check and execute the command "Checkinternet" `verificaInternet`

Comment: @KevinJhon - Okay, I think I understand better what you're trying to do. I posted some sample code that I think will address your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should override oncreate method and call setContentView like your Splash activity